# Copy a file to the Relative path of myClass

Tags: java, file, inputstream, relative-path

This is my app directory

```
----dist
       +-- lib //library folder
       +-- backup //folder with my database backup filename = database_file.sqlite
       |__ app.jar
       |__ database_file.sqlite
```

When I perform the action to a button I want to close database connection and after that to copy (overwrite) the **database_file.sqlite** from **backup** folder to the root folder (**dist**) where the **database_file.sqlite** it's loaded into my app. Shortly, I want to reload a backup/original database when a button is clicked.
Note: I use a default package
For now I have this code (see bellow), but I can't figure out how to make it works.

```
private void cmd_backupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really want to reset your data / Backup database?", "Backup", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (p == 0) {
            InputStream inStream = null;
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            try {

                rs.close();
                pst.close();


                File afile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tzontonel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RDSS\\dist\\backup\\database_file.sqlite");
                File bfile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tzontonel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RDSS\\dist\\database_file.sqlite");
                System.out.println(afile.getCanonicalPath());

                inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

                }

                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();

                // delete the original file
                // afile.delete();

                System.out.println("File is copied successful!");


            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }


        }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: database_file.sqlite(The system cannot find the file specified)` I also modified the `OutputStream` to null. The problem consist in the path (relative path). I don't want to make it hard by a absolute path, which it works, I wanted relative to migration of different OS, system's. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you really need to reinitialize afile since inStream is already assigned with backup stream properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class loader doesn't access the file system. It accesses resources that are in the classpath. You don't want to use the class loader here, but file IO. So the call to `getResourceAsStream()` doesn't make sense (and you replace the input stream it returns by another one anyway).

Put your class in a package, as all classes should be.

Now, when you create a File like this:

```
new File("database_file.sqlite")
```

you open a file that is in the current directory. And the current directory is the directory from which the java command is executed. So, unless you are always in the `dist` directory when executing your program, you won't be able to open the file by using such a relative path.

Pass the path of the `dist` directory as an argument or system property to your application, and use this directory as a base directory to open your files.

The next problem is that you open an input stream and an output stream to the same file, at the same time. You should open an InputStream to the backup file, and an output stream to the database file.

Comment: see the updated question, with absolute path it works, but I want to make it relative to avoid portability error (The system cannot find the file specified). So it works with: `File afile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tzontonel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RDSS\\dist\\backup\\database_file.sqlite");
                File bfile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tzontonel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RDSS\\dist\\database_file.sqlite");`

Comment: See my original answer: pass the root directory as an argument to your program.